# p:tree ajax loading nodes does not display the expand icon

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, tree

I'm trying to ajax load the p:tree component. The idea is to mimic the tree of a windows file system. When I click the expand icon of a node, I make a call to a service which returns list of directories under that directory node. I then simply add these new directories as child nodes of the node which was expanded. I can successfully add child nodes to a node, however, I need to see the expand icon beside every new node being added. This is not happening for me. Any child nodes I add render without the expand icon and thus I am unable to go deeper into the tree.

Furthermore, it seems that PF tree component will only display the expand icon it the node has one or more children. However, in my case, I don't know whether a node will have children or not until that node is expanded.

The source code is available at the PimeFaces forum, I am opening this question in the hopes of getting a few more eyes looking at it.
http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=34819

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find a workaround for this.

Everytime I add a new node anywhere on the tree, add a 'dummy' node to it. This will ensure that every new node added will get the expand icon beside. Now, when clicking the expand icon on a node, the backing bean will remove all children and add the real nodes.

There is probably a better way of doing this so I am open to other suggestions but for the time being this will do its job.